# NPM doesn't add caret as prefix before package version

Tags: npm, package.json, prefix

When I install any package using

```
npm install <packagename> --save
```

Before it was used to add ^ before the prefix but then I replaced ^ with ~ .

Now none of them appear as prefix before the package version in package.json file

How can I bring back the default which is ^.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you install your package without angle bracket you can see the package with ^.

npm install package --save

you will see in package.json file

"package": "^x.xx.x"

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

`npm config set save-exact false`

`npm config set save-prefix="^"` or `npm config set save-prefix="~"`